# How to append a character to a number in an input field using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field of type text and bound to a property in a scope.

```
<input type=text= ng-model="vm.someProperty">
```

If someProperty has a value of 4.32, I want the input to display `4.32%`. I don't want someProperty to equal 4.32%. The value stays the same. Only the display changes. When the page renders, the % character shows up after the value. When the user is changing the input value, only the number shows and when the input loses focus, the % shows again.
I know this can be done using a directive but I am not sure how. I am not proficient in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```js
angular
  .module("docsSimpleDirective", [])
  .controller("Controller", [
    "$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.text = '';
    }
  ])
  .directive("percent", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on("focusout", function() {
          var str = element.val();
          element.val(str + "%");
        });

        element.on("focus", function() {
          var str = element.val();
          element.val(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <input type "text" id="someProperty" percent ng-model="text"> {{text}}
</div>
```

Comment: The % doesn't show when the page renders but I added that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.percentSymbol = function (type) {
      vm.someProperty = vm.replace(/\%/g, '') + '%';
};
```

---

```
<input type=text= ng-model="vm.someProperty" ng-blur = "vm.percentSymbol()">
```

Answer (score -1):

In your html

```
<input ng-focus="onFocus(someProperty)" ng-blur="onBlur(someProperty)" ng-model="someProperty" />
```

in your controller

```
$scope.someProperty= '';
$scope.onFocus = function(someProperty) {
    $scope.someProperty = (someProperty.length >0)? someProperty.split("%")[0] : '';
}

$scope.onBlur = function(someProperty) {
   $scope.someProperty = (someProperty.length >0)? someProperty+'%' : '';
}
```

This working fine.. Hope this will help.

Comment: This doesn't meet my requirement of someProperty having a numeric value only. Can't add '%' to the value. It's for display only.